# Template deduction in dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-cast, template-argument-deduction

I have a class that is defined as the following:

```
template <class WidgetType>
class CometWidget : public WidgetType;
```

Inside a function I am doing this:

```
dynamic_cast<CometWidget *>(iter2->second.second)->changesCommited_();
```

and it resolves the `CometWidget` type, complies and run correctly.
The code runs inside the `CometWidget` class.

How on earth does this happen?
Why is that so? Should it even compile?

Comment: Can you add the function source code? If it's inside the declaration of `CometWidget` then you don't need to explicitly qualify the template (or whatever term you use to say `CometWidget<...>`).

Comment: It is inside CometWidget. Add this as an answer and I'll upvote you. Do you know why it happens.

Comment: It's martian technology, don't ask ...

Comment: I thought that class template argument deduction was supported only from c++17 (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)). That's obviously not the standard used at the time this was posted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's inside the declaration of `CometWidget` then you don't need to explicitly qualify the template (or whatever term you use to say `CometWidget<...>`).

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting indeed. It seems to me like an interesting compiler bug.

It is possible to deduce the correct argument of the CometWidget<> template - just the same way you can deduce template parameters of a function from argument list. If it would be static cast, it would be less surprising.

With dynamic cast, there's little expected to be in common between the source and the target type. So, such "guessing" might have occurred, but then it's not a rightful one.

What compiler is this?

Comment: @the_drow yes MSN is right. The "CometWidget" is called the "injected class name". If you write it from within the template, then it's equivalent to the name with the parameter list followed and names a type, not the template.